# JavaScript - Select a class then remove the pound sign and then perform a sum

Tags: javascript, string, sum, multiplication

I'm using the chrome console to attempt to create a string to do the following:
Take the price from a page & multiply it.

I've got this far, but I am at a basic level in JavaScript.

```
document.querySelector(".classname").innerHTML;
```

&

```
.replace(/\u00A3/g, '');
```

However I am not sure how to combine these 2 strings so that once it finds the price with the first string it then removes the pound sign with the second, any assistance would be very appreciated!

If you're not understanding what I mean then I am very sorry!

Comment: is the pound sign before or after the number?

Comment: Before the number :)

Comment: Give us an example what is the desirec output

Comment: Currently what is displayed is £75. I'm looking to make this appear as £300 by multiplying this by 4 - which I believe requires me to remove the pound sign, is that correct?

Comment: You may use `replace(/£(\d+)/, function($0, $1) {return "£"+(Number($1) * 4);})`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what is a price is not an integer?

Comment: @KieranSmith take a look at my answer

Comment: @AdamWolski: It is not a problem, it can all be handled. E.g. with `/£(\d*\.?\d+)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what if the price is displayed as £1,000.78 ? :)

Comment: @AdamWolski: Just use the appropriate regex, it is not a problem

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my point is that the regex should remove anything that is not a digit or a dot

Comment: @AdamWolski: Once you grabbed what is following the currency symbol, you may remove whatever you need. Else, you may remove too much.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you give an example of removing too much in the regex I described ? (remove anything that is not a digit or a dot)

Comment: @AdamWolski: `Price: $100 (x) and $110 (y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```js
function parsePrice(elem) {
    return parseFloat(elem.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")); //remove anything that is not a digit or dot
}

document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach(function(elem){
  elem.innerHTML = '£'+parsePrice(elem)*4
});
```

```html
<div class="test">£75</div>
<div class="test">£15</div>
<div class="test">£25</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience, this has definitely given me somewhere to start!

Comment: Hi Adam, Got this working if there were multiple cases of this across the site how would I make it function more than once?

Comment: @Kieran use `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Returns this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at parsePrice (<anonymous>:2:37)
    at <anonymous>:5:66

Comment: @KieranSmith you have to write a function that iterates through an array